# how to open chrome dev tools without key board shortcut or screen option and save data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There is a small server which trigger and open up a chrome. this chrome does not have file, edit menu at the top and keyboard shortcut are disable.

ask here is how to open chrome devtool in this unique case and save all data specially network capture and memory

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start with command line

--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs

Please check here for other commands below
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/